# How to build git project ignoring everything on .gitignore

Tags: git, build

I always forget to add something on git. Recently I lost part of my project because a folder wasn't on git. It wasn't on .gitignore also, but when you add a git project on your .git project, and run `git add .`, it isn't included by default. Even if you add by hand the folder, it won't work, you have to clean cache.

I always commit this mistake. One way to make sure everything is working, is to clone my project and try to build it. If it build that means everything needed is being used. If not, then I missed something.

However, doing `git clone` on a temporary folder everytime would take time. Isn't there something in git that facilitates what I need? Like checkout to a branch that has only the files being tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

**Before checking out:**

Stash your current working directory using

```
git stash -u
```

This will stash all your working directory files including untracked which have not been committed yet. Later you can pop the stash out using `git stash pop`

**Then:**

In git you can checkout to the origin like so

```
git checkout origin/master
```

Or what ever branch you wish to. If you want to make any changes to `origin/master`, you can checkout your `master` bracnch, make some changes and push. This will be there on the remote branch `origin/master`

Note: This applies to any other branch, here, I am assuming your remote is called `origin`
and you are trying to make changes to `master`.  If your remote is called `something_else` you can checkout to `something_else/your_branch`.

You can see all your branches by

```
git branch -a
```

and remotes by

```
git remote -vv
```

If you want to checkout a specific commit you can do

```
git checkout <commit’s ref>
```

Note: this will create a detached head and git will try to warn you. So any changes here must be made on a new branch

Comment: I dont understand. Will this erase the untracked files?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No, for that you need to stash them

Comment: I think you didnt understand what I mean. I need to temporarly remove all untracked files from my project so I can see if it builds. Not just currently unstashes files but all untracked files like build folder and etc

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs you see by doing stash you save your local work. Then you checkout your remote. Its like cloning your project in a temporary folder. Did I misunderstood you?

Comment: A word of advise: if you want to try building from your remote branch, make a temp branch from your remote branch and do the works there